# Queries extra en codeigniter 3.11 con ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

Tengo un servidor con codeigniter 3.11 y tengo que estar constantemente mandando peticiones de ajax con jQuery para enviar datos y recibirlos. Lo que sucede es que cada vez que mando una petición de ajax se mandan 5 queries extra a la base de datos. Debe ser algo de codeigniter que viene por defecto para comprobar la sesion pero no he encontrado información. Me interesaría que no hiciese esas peticiones y que solo haga las que yo pida. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Translate your question. This is SO Spanish, you should read [el centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help) and read the articles about how to ask.

Comment: code integer es un framework por ende hace cosas que o puedes controlar, manda las consultas por codigo nativo php y solucionas tu solicitud

Comment: @John El caso es que cuando envio una peticion con ajax a codeigniter aunque lo mande a una función vacia se siguen enviando las queries que están en rojo, no es al utilizar las funciones de codeigniter para enviar al bd las queries, si no al recibir las peticiones.

Comment: es correcto siempre se manejan variables y datos en la base de datos aun cuando no llames a ninguno modelo, la unica forma es usar las clases nativas de php y no usar codeigniter